# Meaning of " WARNING:root:image b'img05.jpg' does not have groundtruth difficult flag specified" in evaluation using object detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am using tensorflow object detection API to my own dataset but while performing evaluation, I've got the following warning,

```
WARNING:root:image b'img05.jpg' does not have groundtruth difficult flag specified
```

I already checked the annotation of the said image and the groundtruth was there. The evaluation runs successfully and printed the mAP but every time I evaluated my model, it throws this warning at image 0.